# What is the use of BindingResult interface in spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

Is `BindingResult` useful to bind just exceptions with view, or something else?

what is the exact use of `BindingResult`?

Or is it useful in binding model attribute with view.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Particular example: use a BindingResult object as an argument for a validate method of a [Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) inside a Controller.

Then, you can check this object looking for validation errors:

```
validator.validate(modelObject, bindingResult);  
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {  
    // do something  
}
```

Answer (score 42):

Basically `BindingResult` is an interface which dictates how the object that stores the result of validation should store and retrieve the result of the validation(errors, attempt to bind to disallowed fields etc)

From [Spring MVC Form Validation with Annotations Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20161120115428/http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/):

> [`BindingResult`] is Spring’s object that **holds the result of the
>   validation and binding and contains errors that may have occurred.** The
>   `BindingResult` must come right after the model object that is validated
>   or else Spring will fail to validate the object and throw an
>   exception.
>
> When Spring sees `@Valid`, it tries to find the validator for the
>   object being validated. Spring automatically picks up validation
>   annotations if you have “annotation-driven” enabled. Spring then
>   invokes the validator and puts any errors in the `BindingResult` and
>   adds the BindingResult to the view model.

Answer (score 34):

It's important to note that the order of parameters is actually important to spring. The BindingResult needs to come right after the Form that is being validated. Likewise, the [optional] Model parameter needs to come after the BindingResult.
Example:

Valid:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entry/updateQuantity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateEntryQuantity(@Valid final UpdateQuantityForm form,
                                  final BindingResult bindingResult,
                                  @RequestParam("pk") final long pk,
                                  final Model model) {
}
```

Not Valid:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/entry/updateQuantity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateEntryQuantity(@Valid final UpdateQuantityForm form,
                                  @RequestParam("pk") final long pk,
                                  final BindingResult bindingResult,
                                  final Model model) {
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Well its a sequential process.
The Request first treat by FrontController and then moves towards our own customize controller with @Controller annotation.

but our controller method is binding bean using modelattribute and we are also performing few validations on bean values.

so instead of moving the request to our controller class, FrontController moves it towards one interceptor which creates the temp object of our bean and the validate the values.
if validation successful then bind the temp obj values with our actual bean which is stored in @ModelAttribute otherwise if validation fails it does not bind and moves the resp towards error page or wherever u want.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

From the official [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html):

> General interface that **represents binding results**. Extends the
>   interface for **error registration capabilities**, allowing for a
>   **Validator** to be applied, and adds **binding-specific analysis and model
>   building.**
>
> Serves as **result holder for a DataBinder**, obtained via the
>   DataBinder.getBindingResult() method. BindingResult implementations
>   can also be used directly, for example to invoke a Validator on it
>   (e.g. as part of a unit test).

Comment: Thnaks for your reply but sorry I am not getting what you have written ....i am new to this framework..can you simplify it...????

Comment: @Ajinkya: You might want to quote from something other than the Spring 2.0 docs, too.

Answer (score 2):

BindingResult is used for validation..

Example:-

```
 public @ResponseBody String nutzer(@ModelAttribute(value="nutzer") Nutzer nutzer, BindingResult ergebnis){
        String ergebnisText;
        if(!ergebnis.hasErrors()){
            nutzerList.add(nutzer);
            ergebnisText = "Anzahl: " + nutzerList.size();
        }else{
            ergebnisText = "Error!!!!!!!!!!!";
        }
        return ergebnisText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**BindingResult** in Spring is an object that stores the results of the validation process of a form object (or any object) and provides error information and validation results. This is often used in the context of form processing, especially with Spring MVC.

The basic tasks of BindingResult are:

1. Validation Error Storage:
   *When object validation fails, BindingResult contains information about validation errors, such as errors related to individual form fields.*
2. Decision to Continue or Discontinue Processing:
   *Based on the validation results, you can decide to continue the processing process (e.g. saving data to the database) or interrupt the process in case of errors.*

Example of using BindingResult in a Spring MVC controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/your-form")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("yourObject", new YourObject());
        return "your-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/submit-form")
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("yourObject") YourObject yourObject, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        // Validation of object
        new YourObjectValidator().validate(yourObject, bindingResult);

        // Checking if any errors occurred
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "your-form";
        }
    
        return "success-page";
    }
}
```