# spring mvc controller class is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hql

In my project I have a page which contains email and password field.
my requirement is,after filling username and password fields,when I press submit,It will check username and password fields in database table..and if it match then it will go to the profile page.

so,I have done this:

mycontroller class is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String dologin(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,BindingResult result) {


          try{
           studentService.LoginStudent(student.getEmail(), student.getPassword());

                 if (result.hasErrors()) {
                  return "signin";
                }
              }
              catch(ConstraintViolationException e){

            }

        return "profile";
    }
```

my StudentServiceimpl.java is:

```
public Student LoginStudent(String email, String password) {

        Student student = new Student(email,password);


        studentDao.LoginStudent(student);

        return student;
    }
```

and StudentDao.java is:

```
public void LoginStudent(Student student) {
       String hql = "select student_id from  student  where email = :email and password = :password";

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
        .setParameter("email", student.getEmail())
        .setParameter("password", student.getPassword());

    }
```

now,the problem is If I put any email id and any password it is directly going to the profile page.if the fields are blank then it is also going to the profile page.why it is not checking the fields?

Comment: Did you tried debugging to dig,what is happening after clicking submit button?

Comment: in console no error is showing

Comment: I mean to say did u tried to start server in debug mode and check which method called on you press submit button?

Comment: Is `LoginStudent` being hit ?

Comment: @ Subodh Joshi, I am trying to see.

Comment: So you mean `dologin` method called?

Comment: For starters, you're swallowing an exception, which is never a good idea.

Comment: You are always returning "profile", this is why it is going to profile page. return profile based on condition.

Answer (score 2):

What I think whatever you are doing with result.hasErrors() is not serving well

I think you should treat that if condition like below:

```
 Student student =      studentService.LoginStudent(student.getEmail(), student.getPassword());




             if (student  != null) {
              return "signin";
            }
```

BindingResult class is not appropriate here. It is useful for form validations ( via validate method ).

Please read [What is the use of BindingResult interface in spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413886/what-is-the-use-of-bindingresult-interface-in-spring-mvc)

Also in your hibernate code you are not executing query, do it like below

```
Query query  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
        .setParameter("email", student.getEmail())
        .setParameter("password", student.getPassword());

return query.list();
```

above program is for reference you need do additional work around your code like parsing and all.

Comment: I used your code..But now I am still in the page..Whatever I put in the fields or if I put correct email & password it is staying on the same page

Comment: And why does he even use `BindingResult` if he's fetching "Student" before performing checkout whether `BindingResult` has errors? This is just bad answer.

Comment: I used          " public void LoginStudent(Student student) "..what will be the so the return type is not matching..

Comment: @BranislavLazic - I am trying to tell him not to use BindingResult  here. I am saying him to use alternate logic. Whats bad in that?

Answer (score 0):

See u are not returning by hql query.
return true is that user exists else false.
and your controller should be like this

```
 try {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "signin";
    }
    bool res = studentService.LoginStudent(student.getEmail(), student.getPassword());


    if (res) {
        return "profile";
    } else {
        return "sign_in";
    }
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {

}
return "profile";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole code within `doLogin` method is generally wrong.

```
RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String dologin(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result) {
    // No need for HttpServletRequest request and
    //   HttpServletResponse response
    String urlOrPage  = null;
    // First perform whether result has errors
    if(!result.hasErrors) {
        // If there are no errors, fetch Student
        Student student = studentService.loginStudent(student.getEmail(), student.getPassword());
        // If credentials are wrong, it will return null, if not, it will return Student. 
        if(student != null) {
            urlOrPage = "redirect:/profile";
        } else {
            urlOrPage = "signin";
        }

    } else {
        urlOrPage = "signin";
    }

    return urlOrPage;   
}
```

Considering that:

- You have "/profile" mapping
- Your validation annotations in `Student` class are correctly placed

Comment: I have used your code.but ,every time I enter wrong id & password or blank the fields or correct id/password I am getting the same page..@ Orion telling me not to use binding result..im trying to follow this

Comment: @Salini And how will you know if someone i.e. passes mail like `thisIsAMail` or even registers with `thisIsAMail`? Or how will you make list of banned password patterns like: `1234`, `password`, `asdf` etc? Prefer checking that password is not blank? Prefer checking that password has enough characters? Did you also debug your `loginStudent` method?

Comment: I have a validator class for this..but I cant get whats the point of this questions you have asked  and what I have asked here(my question)